# Why do some perfectly competitive, loss-making firms shutdown and others don't?

Tags: microeconomics, competition, firm, theory-of-the-firm

### Question:

**Why do perfectly competitive, loss-making firms that have (AC>AVC>AR) shutdown but**

**Firms that have (AC>AR>AVC) not shutdown?**

-Both of these types of firms are making a loss. How is it significant that the latter type's AVC is less than AR ? How does that affect whether it shuts down ?**

These two graphs are for the two types of firms in perfectly competitive markets:

- Loss-making firms where their AC > AR & AVC > AR that shutdown
  [image: diagram1]
- Loss-making firms where their AC > AR & AVC < AR that don't shutdown.
  [image: diagram2]

Comment: Your inequalities need to be fixed, I think for the firms that shut down AC>AVC>AR, and for the firms that don't shut down AC>AR>AVC. Can you please fix it for future clarity. Your graphs are fine.

Answer (score 5):

$AVC<AR$ means, without considering fixed cost, the firm is making a profit of $AR-AVC>0$ per unit of output. Compare the two options: keep producing vs  shutdown:

- Keep producing: $\text{Avg Profit}=\underbrace{AR-AVC}_{>0}-AFC$
- Shutdown: $\text{Avg Profit}=0-AFC$

Since $AVC<AR$, staying in production is better since the revenues can be used to offset part of the fixed costs already incurred.

---

$AVC>AR$ means, without considering fixed costs, the firm is making a loss of $AR-AVC<0$ per unit of output. Compare the two options: keep producing vs shutdown:

- Keep producing: $\text{Avg Profit}=\underbrace{AR-AVC}_{<0}-AFC$
- Shutdown: $\text{Avg Profit}=0-AFC$

Since $AVC>AR$, shutting down leads to a smaller loss than staying in production.